# jQuery in console not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQueryify bookmarklet on a page so that I can call jQuery functions from the console. But everytime I invoke a jQuery function on a selected object, I get the error:

```
"TypeError: jQuery("li")[0].children[0].html is not a function
[Break On This Error] jQuery('li')[0].children[0].html();
```

I have tried this in FireBug as well as Google Chrome's Webkit console.

Comment: You are clicking the bookmarklet, correct?  Can you link to the bookmarklet you are using and an example page with what you input?

Comment: Just confirmed this on a page that is already loading jQuery so I don't think it's just the bookmarklet FYI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are no longer working with jQuery objects when using square braces.

```
jQuery("li")[0]
```

This returns you the 1st `li` as a DOMElement, not a jQuery object.

```
jQuery("li")[0].children[0]
```

This returns the 1st `li`'s 1st child as a DOMElement, not a jQuery object.

```
.html()
```

This function only works for jQuery objects.  For DOMElements, you can use the `.innerHTML` property.

I suggest instead of dealing with DOMElements, you should continue working with jQuery objects.  Try using this instead:

```
jQuery('li').eq(0).children().eq(0).html()
```

Comment: Why a down-vote?  **EDIT**: I see why.  `children(0)` should have been `children().eq(0)`.  Fixed :-P

Comment: @Rocket it was my downvote. I'm sorry, just a mistake. +1 for the trouble!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to call a jQuery function, `html`, on a DOM object `children[0]`.  Try wrapping that in a jQuery object and then calling `html`

```
var temp = jQuery("li")[0].children[0];
var html = jQuery(temp).html();
```

Comment: @genesis yes, that's a DOM property.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children

Answer (score 5):

Check the result of `jQuery("li")[0].children[0]` , it's a regular DOM object NOT a jQuery object. Without seeing your HTML i can't recommend a better selector but a cheap and dirty fix would be

`jQuery(jQuery('li')[0].children[0]).html();`

This will convert the DOM object result into a jQuery object which has the `.html()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
jQuery(jQuery("li")[0].children[0]).html();
```

or better one

```
jQuery("li:eq(0)").children(':eq(0)').html();
```

or another one

```
jQuery("li:eq(0)").children().eq(0).html();
```

even this one will work

```
jQuery("li").eq(0).children().eq(0).html();
```

Comment: No, `[0]` returns a DOM object.

Comment: `jQuery("li")[0]` is a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, and therefore has no `children()` function.

Comment: Still `.children(0)` would not work. You perhaps mean `.children(':eq(0)')`.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing the array elements on the jquery object (using []) returns a DOMElement, which obviously doesn't have jquery's methods. You probably want to use `eq()` instead.